# Find the limit $‎{\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}}(x \log(n^2+a^2) + \sum\limits_{k=1}^n \log(k^2+a^2) -‎ ‎\log((k+x)^2+a^2))‎$‎

Tags: calculus, limits, summation, logarithms

I've been stuck with calculating the limit of the following problem. Can you help?

$‎‎\displaystyle{\lim_{n\to\infty}}(x \log(n^2+a^2) + \sum_{k=1}^n\log(k^2+a^2) -‎ ‎‎\log((k+x)^2+a^2))‎$,‎

for $a>0$ and $x\geq 1$.

Comment: $\displaystyle{\lim_{n\to\infty}}(x \log(n^2+a^2))$ does not exist unless $x=0$.

Comment: Agreed, but there are other terms which may cancel. For instance, $\lim_{x\to\infty}x=\infty$, but $\lim_{x\to\infty}x-x=0$.

Comment: I know that $‎‎\displaystyle{\lim_{n\to\infty}}(x \log(n) + \sum_{k=1}^n \log(k) -‎ ‎‎\log(k+x)) = \log ‎\Gamma‎(x+1)‎$‎, for $x\geq 1$.